# Excel Macro to Copy Data From a Worksheet Yields the Query Definition instead of Data

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

As the title says, I'm trying to copy data from a particular file into a new tab in my workbook, but the macro only copies the query definition that (I assume) was used to retrieve the data itself.

I've already removed any connections to external sources, but that didn't fix the problem. Here's a screenshot of the paste results:

[image: Query Definition Paste Results]

Here's the portion of my code I am using to paste:

```
Set DestWS = wkbDest.Sheets(Curr_Input_File)
If Len(wkbDest.Sheets(Curr_Input_File).Range("A1").Value) > 0 Then
    wkbDest.Sheets(Curr_Input_File).UsedRange.ClearContents
    SheetToCopy.UsedRange.Copy
    DestWS.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
Else
    SheetToCopy.UsedRange.Copy
    DestWS.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End If
```

I know the copy/paste loop works since all the other files are copied/pasted without issue. However, for this file only, I'm having the issue as described above. How can I code it to paste the actual data instead of the query? FWIW, I can't see the query anywhere in the source data file.

Comment: There must be a sheet with that query on it. Have you stepped through with the debugger?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the answer is obvious but I figured it out. There was a hidden sheet with the SQL query definition. My copy code was just copying the first tab in the workbook by default `SheetToCopy = wkbSource.Sheets(1)`, thus it was grabbing the SQL query.

I didn't even know you could hide sheets. It's done by going to the Home tab, under the 'Cells' section click Format-->Hide & Unhide-->Unhide Sheet.

Comment: You can also unhide a sheet by Right Clicking any Sheet's Tab and then selecting "Unhide...". From there it will pop up a menu of all the sheets that are hidden and gives you the choice to "unhide."